# Spring MVC return ajax response using Jackson

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a scenario where I am filling a dropdown box in JSP through AJAX response from the server. In the controller, I am retuning a Collection of Product objects and have annotated the return type with @ResponseBody.

Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getServicesForMarket", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Collection<Product> getServices(@RequestParam(value="marketId", required=true) int marketId) {
    Collection<Product> products = marketService.getProducts(marketId);
    return products;
}
```

And Product is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private Market market;

    private Service service;

    private int price;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MARKET_ID")
    public Market getMarket() {
        return market;
    }

    public void setMarket(Market market) {
        this.market = market;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID")
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Column(name = "PRICE")
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Service is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SERVICE")
public class Service implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

In the JSP, I need to get the data from the service field of Product also. So I in my JQuery callback function, I have written like product.service.description to get the data.

It seems that by default Jackson is not mapping the associated service object (or any other custom object). Also I am not getting any exception. In the JSP, I do not get the data. It is working fine when I return Collection of some object which does not contain any other custom objects as its fields.

Am I missing any settings for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding some debugging/logging to your controller to inspect the `service` field for values? If you're not seeing it before the controller return statement then it is not due to Jackson. Also try removing the `FetchType.LAZY` to see if that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all that, the data is coming fully loaded. FetchType.LAZY is not an issue since in the service, I am fetching the data using dynamic fetching in the query, so product.service is loaded with data. Btw, I am using Spring 3.1.2 and have put Jackson 1.9.8 jars.

Comment: Seems strange then... I've used Jackson in the same way and not had a problem. Seeing as you haven't shown us the code for `Service`, it would suggest there might be something about that class. Check the getters and look for any possible `@JsonIgnore` annotations (which suppress JSON output).

Comment: Just updated - I have provided the details for the Service class in the post. Are you also using Jackson 1.9.8 with Spring 3.1.2? I doubt problem due to any version mismatch.

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually the issue was not due to Service object, it was happening due to market object. I never thought about Market object as I was not referring to it. Annotating market getter with @JsonIgnore solved it. Thanks nickdos for your pointers - I caught the exception by placing debugging in the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter. But the exception never boiled up, so could not be traced earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to use hibernate module for [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate), this will help you to ignore hibernate un-initlized objects. this way you will not have exception and only fully initilzed conversion.

Comment: Thanks Jigar for suggeting this. I tried Hibernate module for Jackson and registered the custom Object mapper with Spring as suggested on the link. But it is not working, I am getting the same Lazyinitialization exception in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. Could you please help me out on this? I think there are some more settings to be done.

Comment: I was able to configure successfully. The problem was because of <mvc:annotation-driven /> entry. Because of it there were two instances of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getting created. on configuring the messagesConverter in the mvc:annotation-config, the problem was resolved. The exceptions are no longer coming due to Lazyinitialization. Thanks!